# 60 gb ssd how to partition?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, visual-studio-2010

I have just bought AMD fx 4100 machine with 60 gb ssd.

I need to run win 7 , sql server & vs studio 2010 and later if it space allows dreamweaver and ms office.

i have divided into 2 equal partitions of 30 gb . Is it right. I might add secondary hdd as slave for data storage.

All tips are welcome.

Comment: Why would you want to partition it?  There is no reason to do this with the configuration you have listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

60GB is pretty small for a complete Windows 7 system, therefor my advice would be to create one partition using the full available space.

On Windows all lot of files are always installed onto the partition Windows installed onto and you can't change that in the installer.

If you have already installed Windows on the first partition you delete the second partition. Afterwards you can increase ("extend") the partition size of the first partition.
As you can not extend the system partition that contains the currently running Windows installation you have to boot from Windows 7 install DVD and use the command line tool diskpart.exe:

http://www.pronetworks.org/forums/using-diskpart-on-the-windows-7-dvd-t112571.html

Use the following commands after starting `diskpart.exe`:

```
select disk 0
detail disk
```

Look at the output and make a mental note of the volume number of the system volume/partition. Insert the number in the next command:

```
select volume <nr>
extend
```

Comment: already created 2 ...how to revert back...

Comment: @superb1, please note that 32-bit requires 16 GB available hard disk where as the 64-bit requires 20 GB. This could be 1/3 of your hard drive gone straight away. I'd be very conscious about what you install and consider a second HDD. http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/products/system-requirements

Comment: Please post a new question on how to revert back and mark Robert as the answer to your original question (if you feel it was the answer to the original question).

Comment: See my updated answer.